# How can I make `string-rectangle` show the changes I'm about to make to the buffer?

Tags: emacs24.4, rectangle

For a while, I was building prerelease versions of 24.4. One of the features that I liked was that when I used `string-rectangle` (via <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>), the string that I was typing showed up live in the buffer. This let me see what I was changing in context.

However, when I upgraded to the release version of 24.4, that functionality disappeared. I gave a quick look at `rect.el`, but I didn't see any appropriate variables that might help. Is there a way of enabling this feature again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the prerelease versions you were building had the version number 24.4.50?  That means that they're actually prerelease versions of 24.5, which was later renamed to 25.1 (but still not released at the time of this writing).

If so, you actually *downgraded* to the release version of 24.4, and thus lost this feature.  I'm currently running 25.0.50, and this feature is available to me and mentioned in the NEWS file as a new feature in 25.1.

Comment: Well, that certainly makes sense. I was using Homebrew and just building from `HEAD`. I know that 24.4 hadn't been released at the time, but perhaps the 24.4 branch had already been forked (or other plausible explanations).